# Why can't I create an edge constraint in SQL Server 2019 with VS 2019 Community

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

I cannot create edge constraints. There's a description of the syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/graph-edge-constraints?view=sql-server-2017.).

I have the SQL Server 2019 Release Candidate 1. I don't completely understand how this relates to CTPs, but I assumed that whatever was on the [Eval Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2019-rc/) is the good stuff. No?

If I paste the example into a SSMS 18.2, I get "Incorrect Syntax" at the definition of the edge constraint. I can see artifacts like sys.edge_constraints and sys.edge_constraint_clauses...but it won't let me define the constraint. What am I missing?

The example I'm trying (from the first link) is:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
   (
      ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
      , CustomerName VARCHAR(100)
   )
   AS NODE;
GO
CREATE TABLE Supplier
   (
      ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
      , SupplierName VARCHAR(100)
   )
   AS NODE;
   GO
CREATE TABLE Product
   (
      ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
      , ProductName VARCHAR(100)
   )
   AS NODE;

-- CREATE edge table with edge constraints.
CREATE TABLE bought
   (
      PurchaseCount INT
      , CONSTRAINT EC_BOUGHT CONNECTION (Customer TO Product, Supplier TO Product)
   )
   AS EDGE;

-- Query sys.edge_constraints and sys.edge_constraint_clauses to view
-- edge constraint properties.
SELECT
   EC.name AS edge_constraint_name
   , OBJECT_NAME(EC.parent_object_id) AS edge_table_name
   , OBJECT_NAME(ECC.from_object_id) AS from_node_table_name
   , OBJECT_NAME(ECC.to_object_id) AS to_node_table_name
   , is_disabled
   , is_not_trusted
FROM sys.edge_constraints EC
   INNER JOIN sys.edge_constraint_clauses ECC
   ON EC.object_id = ECC.object_id
WHERE EC.parent_object_id = object_id('bought');
```

Similarly, I have a SQL Server Database project targeting *SQL Server 2019 or Azure SQL Database Managed Instance*...and the table artifacts produce the same error at the same place in the table definitions.

**Update:**

As Dan Guzman suggested - the tooling must be lagging a touch. The thing I did to experiment and prove it out in my VS project was to add the following to my Post-Deploy script:

```
execute sp_executesql @statement = N'alter table graph.VotesFor add 
  constraint [People.VoteFor.Candidates] 
  connection 
  ( 
    graph.People to graph.Candidates 
  )
'
```

This applied the constraint w/o tooling support - only the db engine...which was totally happy to work. It gets me past my immediate concern. I understand that SSDT is no longer separate from VS, but comes with the "Data storage and processing" workload in a VS installation. I should have mentioned previously that I've always had that workload selected.

So, this leads me to wonder if previous stand-alone SSDT installations are conflicting with the VS-deployed variant...or if it's just not in-the-box yet. Will piddle around and see what I can discover.

Comment: Your SQL works fine in **[this SQL Server 2019 db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=51d83b11b52d47e536568635929c721a)** though... Maybe the issue is more related to SSIS 18.2?

Comment: Yes - thanks...makes me think *something* is messed up in my dev box. I also have 2017 as the default instance...with 2019 as a named instance. Don't know if something got crossed up.

Comment: I think SSDT may be lagging behind with it's parser and model. See [this SSDT parsing error question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b09fed02-5d2d-4c26-8caa-3af9bd764525/ssdt-parser-error-sql46010-but-no-error-in-management-studio).